# UITableViewStyleGrouped remove separator only for header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a couple sections. When I use `UITableViewStylePlain` it does **not** put any separator on the bottom of the headers, while each cell **does** have a separator. This is the look I want, *however*, I want the behavior of `UITableViewStyleGrouped` that when you scroll the header moves with the scrolling rather than staying in place.

But when I switch to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` a separator shows up between the header and the first cell.

How can I get rid of this separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the contentOffset according to the contentInset in the UITableViewControllerDelegate (extends UIScrollViewDelegate) like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;


if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
       scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
   } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
       scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Huh? I'm confused. this gets rid of the separator?

Comment: I m confused also as you are asking or telling? This will only make your header go away while scrolling you can still use you old code that is with plain style.

Comment: ah i see. not answering "does this get rid of the separator?", but a method to modify the section header upon scrolling.

Comment: Yes you have to use plain style but you want your header to go away as you scroll so this will make header go away in plain style .. You don't need to use grouped tableview

Comment: actually for me there was a bit of a delay - so i changed it to this: - `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0);
```